# Route thru 2 Access Points (APs)

Tags: networking, routing, access-point

I have a network as follows:

```
-----------
 AP
192.168.2.1
-----------
 |
-----------
192.168.2.2
 Box1/AP1
192.168.1.1
-----------
 |
-----------
192.168.2.3
 Box2
-----------
```

So Box1 is connected to the main AP and Box2 is connected to Box1 (also an AP). Box 1 has 2 radios in it so one radio is configured as an AP and one is configured as a client. Box1's IP that the AP can see is 192.168.2.2. Box2 has an IP of 192.168.2.3. It's AP has an IP of 192.168.1.1. I use the command 'ip route add 192.168.2.3 via 192.168.1.1' so box 1 can see 192.168.2.1 (Main AP), itself 192.168.2.2 and Box 2 192.168.2.3. What route/iptables command can I give to see 192.168.2.3 from the main AP (192.168.2.1)?

Comment: This makes no sense. Wireless Access Points are layer 2 devices. They are not Layer 3 devices. You need a router to route traffic between Layer 3 networks.

Comment: So how do mesh access points route traffic? Keep in mind that these are linux devices  and can be programmed.  Can I turn Box1, Box2, or AP into a router and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of joeqwerty sais, it is not possible to fix that with routing / iptables itself because of the layers.

However, you might be able to solve your problem, if you create a VPN-Tunnel trough the devices i.e. with OpenVPN, because the layer 3 will be "encapsulated" this way. This would be no real solution but only a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by making sure my second interface had the proper netmasks.  Then I added a route in my AP to Box2.  I now can ping and access Box2 from the AP.